# R legend color doesn't match plotting points

Tags: r, plot, colors, legend, factors

I have a process the retrieves data from the internet and formats for plotting.  Sequential data points are paired with flags that change over time, and I want these flags to be the basis of the point colors.  There is a very large and unpredictable library of possible flags, so don't know ahead of time what flags will be used.  I can't get the legend color to match the point color.

The code below provides a analog of data set and an example of the mismatch between the plotting point and legend point color.  The examples I've seen depend on knowing the flags ahead of time.  Sorry if this is simple and thanks for the help!

```
myx<-seq(1:100); myy<-rnorm(100); mydf<-data.frame(myx,myy)
mydf$flag<-NA
mydf$flag[1:30]<-"Flag A"; mydf$flag[31:60]<-"Flag B"; mydf$flag[61:100]<-"Flag C"
plot(mydf$myx, mydf$myy, type="b", col=factor(mydf$flag), pch=19)
legend("bottomright", legend=levels(factor(mydf$flag)),
   col=factor(mydf$flag),
   pch=19)
```

Comment: Hi, you can add the **unique** function like this in legend **col=unique(factor(mydf$flag))**

Comment: If the order of the flags changes (as it will in the real data set), this solution seems not to capture that order change.  I think I need to set an unambiguous color assignment to each flag of a flexible list of flags and carry that through for both the plotting and the legend.

Comment: If your don't know what the range of possible values of the flag variable are then you cannot specify a rule to assign colors. Please clarify the problem statement.

Comment: The plot statement handles the variability of the flags with no difficulty.  It will expand or contract the number of colors to match the unique number of flags.  The challenge is maintaining a link between the selected flag color and the flag label in the df so that the legend fully matches the color assignment in the plot.  I have a work around for the moment that collapses the full range of flags into 3 categories.  But that still doesn't answer my original question.

Answer (score 0):

`col=as.numeric(unique(factor(mydf$flag)))` in the legend call works:

```
myx<-seq(1:100); myy<-rnorm(100); mydf<-data.frame(myx,myy)
mydf$flag<-NA
mydf$flag[1:30]<-"Flag A"; mydf$flag[31:60]<-"Flag B"; mydf$flag[61:100]<-"Flag C"
plot(mydf$myx, mydf$myy, type="b", col=factor(mydf$flag), pch=19)
legend("bottomright", legend=levels(factor(mydf$flag)),
   col=as.numeric(unique(factor(mydf$flag))),
   pch=19)
```

[image]